# What is the physical reason of anomalous dispersion in Lorentz model?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, frequency, dielectric, dispersion

- According to the [Lorentz model of dispersion](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=lorentz+dispersion+model), a dielectric has a bunch of resonant frequencies $\{\omega_{0j}\}$ for $j=1,2,...$.
- In a frequency interval around any resonant frequency $\omega_0$, the refective index $n$ decreases with increasing $\omega$. In particular, $n=c/v_p$ ($v_p=\omega/k$ being the phase velocity in the medium, which can exceed $c$), is $>1$ for $\omega<\omega_0$ and $<1$ for $\omega>\omega_0$ in the anomalous region.

This phenomenon is called anomalous dispersion. What is the physical reason of this behaviour around $\omega=\omega_0$ in the Lorentz model of dispersion?

Comment: Can't give an answer now, but note that the region of anomalous dispersion widens with increase of the damping parameter $\gamma$ of the Lorentz function. See also [this demo](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DrudeLorentzModelForDispersionInDielectrics/)

Answer (score 1):

The radiation causes polarisation of the molecules. The greater the polarisation, the greater the refractive index (i.e. the more the radiation is slowed down by the material.)

Polarisation is greatest when the exciting frequency matches the resonant frequency.

So if you consider  $\omega$ increasing from small values towards $\omega_0$, the refractive index increases (normal dispersion) to a maximum at $\omega=\omega_0$, and then falls again (anomalous dispersion) as $\omega$ increases away from $\omega_0$.

When you do the maths you find that the increase is long and slow and the decrease is shorter and faster, so most materials at most frequencies are on the upward slope: normal dispersion is thus common and anomalous dispersion is rarer - hence the names.

Comment: I think you are explaining the mechanism of normal dispersion. I am asking what is the mechanism for anomalous behaviour.

Comment: Normal dispersion is below the resonance. Anomalous dispersion is above the resonance. The mechanism is the same.

Comment: I do not understand why you say that normal dispersion is below the resonance and anomalous is above it. Normal dispersion happens away from the resonant frequency $\omega_0$ on either side of $\omega_0$. Similarly, anomalous dispersion happens in a region around $\omega_0$ on either side of it.

Comment: No. http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/Class/phy319/phy319/node50.html

Comment: I fail to get the point. Your linked diagram shows that in a small window around the resonace point, there is anomalous dispersion, exactly what I said above.

Comment: Minimum and maximum of the refractive index are to the sides of the resonance frequency, not at it.